# Pytest: how to use --basetemp value in script

Tags: python, pytest

I have tests where I need to create some files.
Right now it looks like and I don't use temp directories.

```
class TestGraphProcessing:
    @pytest.mark.parametrize("graph, path_to_save", GRAPH_TO_FILE)
    def test_save_graph(self, graph, path_to_save):
        save_graph(graph, path_to_save)
        assert path_to_save.is_file()
        path_to_save.unlink()

    ...
```

I know that it's possible to use `--basetemp` to create a temporary directory. But how is it possible to fetch it into your test script?

Or is it possible to create and remove files during testing more elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tmp_path` fixture. There's an example test in the [docs](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/tmp_path.html):

```
# content of test_tmp_path.py
CONTENT = "content"


def test_create_file(tmp_path):
    d = tmp_path / "sub"
    d.mkdir()
    p = d / "hello.txt"
    p.write_text(CONTENT)
    assert p.read_text() == CONTENT
```